# Why does interpolating NaNs result in an empty plot?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I think my toy example below is self-explanatory. Basically, I can plot a line based on 5 values, yet if I interpolate `NaN`s the resulting line plot is empty. I would expect that matplotlib would still be able to connect the discrete existing points in my data (which are all still present).

```
a = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5], index=range(0, 10, 2), columns=['value'])
print(a)

  value
0   1
2   2
4   3
6   4
8   5

a.plot()
```

[image]

```
b = pd.DataFrame([np.NaN]*5, index=range(1, 11, 2), columns=['value'])
print(pd.concat([a, b]).sort_index())

    value
0   1.0
1   NaN
2   2.0
3   NaN
4   3.0
5   NaN
6   4.0
7   NaN
8   5.0
9   NaN
pd.concat([a, b]).sort_index().plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Well, when plotting line segments, all segments where either the start or the end is `NaN` are skipped. That way, you can draw part of a curve, then a gap and then the rest of the curve. To draw the points in your case, use `pd.concat([a, b]).sort_index().plot(marker='*')`

Comment: but why not extend a segment past a NaN to the next defined value?

Comment: It will only connect consecutive points, which you do not have in the toy dataset.

Comment: I think I see. Btw, your suggestion works nicely for my actual case, thanks!

Comment: @JoshFriedlander If matplotlib would skip the `NaN`s instead of making gaps, you'd lose that very useful functionality. Also, the gaps make missing values more visible in case they wouldn't be intentional. In case you really want the `NaN`s skipped, you can always create a new dataframe where you skip those and then plot.

Comment: yes, I was previously doing `fillna(method='ffill')`. At first I thought that the correct behaviour would be to connect the existing data (since all line plots of discrete data are anyway implicit regression). But when there is _known_ missing data, regression is incorrect behaviour, since it masks data _known to be missing_, which might be quite different.